# Saving a NSArray that contains a NSDictionary that contains an NSArray of UIImages (and others)

Tags: iphone, uiimage, save, nscoding

I've seen various questions here pertaining to saving NSArrays/NSDictionaries, but I'm a bit confused about what to do when some of the subelements are UIImages.

To give a little context, the app is essentially a blog-type app.  When the user is composing a new entry, their post can contain the following:

- Up to 3 images from their photo album
- Text
- Location

In essence, I'm trying to implement a "Save Draft" functionality to the app if the user decides to temporarily cancel their blog post.  When the user cancels the blog post, they will be asked in a UIActionSheet if they would like to save their draft.  When the user wants to post again, they can begin from where they left off with their saved draft.

At this point, I would need to save these following objects:

```
1) NSArray of selected photos
---> contains NSDictionaries (up to 3)
--------> UIImage (large sized version)
--------> UIImage (thumbnail sized version)

2) NSDictionary of NSValues (just some view x,y position data)

3) Text -- NSString data of the blog text they have written

4) Location text -- NString data of their current location
```

Given that I need to save the above 1~4 data in order to make the "Save Draft" functinality, what is the best way to do this?  Should I make  a special class to hold all of this data?  Also, do I first need to make the UIImages into NSData before I can save them to disk?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a class/model like structure make more sense and easier to handle as well.
Something like-

```
Interface Blogdata 
     NSArray *selectedPhoto;
     NSDictionary *positionValues;
     NSString *blogText;
     NSString *locationText;
```

and then you can make one more model for photo data;

```
Interface Photodata
     NSDictionary *photo;
     UIImage *largeImage;
     UIImage *thumbImage;
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm still confused about the UIImage handling.  Suppose I create a model as such for Photodata with UIImage objects.  Will the UIImage objects serialize as is, or do I have to first convert them to NSData first, and then serialize the Photodata?

Comment: if you have NSData then you can use that in either way- 1. store in NSData instead of UIImage and when you need that image then convert(although a bit memory consuming) 2.store in uiimage directly(after conversion from nsdata to uiimage)

Answer (score 1):

All of the properties that you mentioned seem like they would belong in a `Blog` class. Are they already grouped together? A `Blog` object could capture the state of the draft with variables (properties) of the object being the four things you mentioned. You can then save the `Blog` object as NSData and read it when the user wants the draft again.

The advantage of this is that you only have to worry about saving one object, instead of having to think about saving four each time (and retrieving them).

Comment: Not yet in a class at this point, but it sure makes sense to do so.  However, even if I make a Blog class, wouldnt I have to convert the UIImages to NSData anyway?  Or can the Blog class have the UIImages as is and just save the Blog class itself as NSData?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to save the images to the apps documents folder and save the NSArray of filenames and other data that can be represented as text in a drafts.plist.

```
filenameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image1.png"];
fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByAppendingString:filenameStr];
NSData    *imageData    = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```